# Is this decomposition in 3NF?

Tags: database-theory, databases, decomposition

I have the following question:

> Consider relation R(A, B, C, D, E, F, H) with the following functional dependencies: 
> A --> D, AE --> H, DF --> BC, E --> C, H --> E 
> Consider three relational schema R1(A, D), R2(E, C), and R3(A, B, E, F, H). They form a decomposition for R. 
> (a) Do the original functional dependencies apply in R1, R2, and R3? 
> (b) Is this decomposition in 3NF? Explain your answer.

My attempt:

(a) The original functional dependencies apply in R1, R2, and R3 as long as the relation contains the attributes in the functional dependencies.

(b) No. Keys in R3 = {AEF, AFH}. From {AF}+ = {ABCDF} in R, in R3 {AF}+ = {ABF}. Hence we can form a functional dependency AF --> B, and the LHS of this functional dependency does not contain a key. The RHS also does not contain only key attributes.

The solution provided did not address (a) directly, and stated that the decomposition is in 3NF because the original FDs do not violate 3NF. Would like to know what I did wrongly here. Thank you!

Comment: ABE is also a key, also AF->B would be a dependency by using the axiom of pseudotransitivity. When you check the FDs for 3NF you would find their RHS to be a prime/key attribute, which is sufficient to say they are in 3NF

Comment: Could you explain why ABE is also a key (in R3/the original table)? Not very sure why but I can't reach F from ABE...

Comment: as I said AF->B would be a dependency in R3. If you look carefully in the original table you have A->D and DF->BC. Using axiom of pseudotransitivity you can infer AF->BC and hence AF->B would be a dependency in R3. You can now find out the candidate keys and you'll understand.

Comment: Thanks! I see, so in R3(A, B, E, F, H) the candidate keys will be AEF and AFH? Which means R3 is not in 3NF, since AF->B is a dependency, and B is not a key attribute?